# How to call a php template from a twig template

Tags: php, templates, symfony, twig

I have two template files. One is a twig template and another is a php template file. Rendering both directly from the controller works, but when I want to render de php template inside the twig template using the `{% include 'mytemplate.html.php' %}` but then Symfony uses Twig to parse the template, not the php template engine.

How do I tell Twig to render the template file as a php template instead of a Twig template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to write an extension for Twig. The extension could provide function which will take PHP template name as an argument and will render it. Why are you using two different templating engines?

Comment: well I wanted to do some complex things than are possible in Twig and didn't want to write extensions for twig. So just a quick hack basically. But I was also wondering if you use different bundles which in turn use different template engines and wanted to use templates from both if it would be poosible.

Comment: @jtietema Actually, writing extensions for Twig is *very* easy, trust me. Just follow the official docs at http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions.html